# Custom font not working in Firefox 3.6!

Tags: css, firefox

My custom font defined on http://flamefusion.net does not render correctly in Firefox 3.6.

It is rendering as Verdana, which is set as the fall-back font in the CSS, defined here: http://flamefusion.net/style/site.css

The code there is generated by Typekit, here: http://typekit.com/

*For those who says that it is not possible, I would like to point out that it is, in CSS 3, which I am trying to use. See the font-face selector for more information, here: http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/, or use Typekit.*

Here's a screenshot of how the page looks like in Chrome 8, which is how it is supposed to look like regarding the fonts. They also work in IE6 or higher, as well as Opera.
[image: This is how it should look like]

Comment: I've fixed the broken link in the question. It's worth noting that this question is about CSS fonts in WOFF format.

Comment: First of all, the link wasn't broken. You broke it. Second of all, it's not just about WOFF. As you can see, I embedded TTF, and all other kinds of formats too.

Comment: You know what would help us? A picture of what the site should look like.

Comment: Anyone can see the site in any other browser than Firefox, to see what it should look like. But point taken, I will upload a screenshot.

Comment: @Mathias: Alright, sorry, I've reverted the link to the one that returns a 404 error message.

Comment: (was asking because this font _may_ looks bad on windows vista anyway as shown [here](http://typekit.com/fonts/colaborate#browse-browser-samples) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it fixed. It turns out that Firefox 3.6 (and possibly others too) does not allow cross-domain content when it comes to fonts. That's kind of lame if you ask me, but moving it to the main domain solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mathias post, this is the way (using .htaccess) to allow this if moving the files aren't possible:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Nice addition! Didn't know that.